# C++: Use a reflection to loop over elements in a struct?

Tags: c++, reflection

I have the following codes which work fine. Basically it is going over all pointers in `my_struct`, apply `my_fun` on each pointer and assign the corresponding output to `my_array`.

```
   enum class MyEnum {
       head = 0,
       tail = 1,
       left_head = 2,
       left_tail = 3,
       right_head = 4,
       right_tail = 5,
   };

    auto head_ptr = my_struct.head_;
    auto tail_ptr = my_struct.tail_;
    auto left_head_ptr = my_struct.left_head_;
    auto left_tail_ptr = my_struct.left_tail_;
    auto right_head_ptr = my_struct.right_head_;
    auto right_tail_ptr = my_struct.right_tail_;

    if (head_ptr) {
        my_array[static_cast<size_t>(MyEnum::head)] = my_fun(head_ptr);
    }

    if (tail_ptr) {
        my_array[static_cast<size_t>(MyEnum::tail)] = my_fun(tail_ptr);
    }

    if (left_head_ptr) {
        my_array[static_cast<size_t>(MyEnum::left_head)] = my_fun(left_head_ptr);
    }

    if (left_tail_ptr) {
        my_array[static_cast<size_t>(MyEnum::left_tail)] = my_fun(left_tail_ptr);
    }

    if (right_head_ptr) {
        my_array[static_cast<size_t>(MyEnum::right_head)] = my_fun(right_head_ptr);
    }

    if (right_tail_ptr) {
        my_array[static_cast<size_t>(MyEnum::right_tail)] = my_fun(right_tail_ptr);
    }
```

I am wondering is there a more elegant way to do this? Maybe something like the reflection in Java? Thanks a lot!

Comment: C++ doesn't have reflection, some libraries exist, mostly using MACRO to define the struct.

Comment: @Jarod42 Could you please advice how to use MARCRO for this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show `my_struct` ? As it seems you might simply do `auto ptrs[] = {my_struct.head_, my_struct.tail_, my_struct.left_head_, my_struct.left_tail_, my_struct.right_head_, my_struct.right_tail_}; for (int i = 0; i != 6; ++i) { if (ptrs[i]) {my_array[i] = my_fun(ptrs[i]);}}`.

Comment: A `to_tuple`/`as_tie` function would allow to loop over your members with a cleaner way (if member are of different types). else `to_array`.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be to use apply and tie:

```
auto assign = [](std::size_t ith, auto& member) {
    if (member) {
        my_array[ith] = my_fun(member);
    }
};

std::apply(
    [&assign](auto&... members) {
        std::size_t ith = 0;
        (assign(ith++, members), ...);
    },
    std::tie(
        my_struct.head_,
        my_struct.tail_,
        my_struct.left_head_,
        my_struct.left_tail_,
        my_struct.right_head_,
        my_struct.right_tail_
    )
);
```

In C++20 however you can use expansion statements to iterate over an aggregate type:

```
std::size_t ith = 0;
for...(auto& member : my_struct) {
    if (member) {
        my_array[ith++] = my_fun(member);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just using a map or unordered_map, depending on your exact usage.

```
struct my_struct {
  std::map<MyEnum, Value* ptr> values;
}
```

Then your array builder becomes:

```
for (const auto&[key, value] : my_struct_instance.values) {
  my_array[static_cast<size_t>(key)] = my_fun(value);
}
```